# count no.of occurrences per unique id

Tags: perl, awk

I am new to command line. I have long text file (samp.txt) with following columns with space delimited. Awk/sed/perl help appreciated.

```
Id           Pos Re   Va  Cn   SF:R1   SR  He  Ho NC       
c|371443199  22  G     A    R   Pass:8   0   1  0  0       
c|371443199  25  C     A    M   Pass:13  0   0  1  0
c|371443199  22  G     A    R   Pass:8   0   1  0  0        
c|367079424  17  C     G    S   Pass:19  0   0  1  0      
c|371443198  17  G     A    R   Pass:18  0   1  0  0       
c|367079424  17  G     A    R   Pass:18  0   0  1  0
```

I want count for each unique id (count unique id how many occurrences), count 6th column (6th column =pass), count how many He (from 8th column) and how many Ho (9 th column). I would like to get result like this

```
Id            CountId  Countpass   CountHe CountHO
cm|371443199   3        3          2        1
cm|367079424   2        2          0        2
```

Comment: Is `Countpass` always the same as `CountId`? You don't show any examples that are not counted.

Comment: I want count no.of occurence of pass for each unique id.

Comment: @user1440683 Your first id has three lines, but two identical "passes". You say this should count as 3, but you don't really specify how. I suspect you made a typo in the id `c|371443198`, which you have also excluded from the expected output.

Comment: @user1440683: -1: have you tried to solve this yourself? It isn't very difficult. Please demonstrate that you have made some effort and aren't just looking for software written for free. I have voted to close as the problem is very unclear.

Comment: So some records say something other than "Pass"? Show an example, please.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ids[$1]++; pass[$1] = "?"; he[$1] += $8; ho[$1] += $9} END {OFS = "\t"; print "Id", "CountId", "Countpass", "CountHe", "CountHO"; for (id in ids) {print id, ids[id], pass[id], he[id], ho[id]}' inputfile
```

Broken out onto multiple lines:

```
awk '{
    ids[$1]++;
    pass[$1] = "?";     # I'm not sure what you want here
    he[$1] += $8; 
    ho[$1] += $9
} 
END {
    OFS = "\t"; 
    print "Id", "CountId", "Countpass", "CountHe", "CountHO"; 
    for (id in ids) {
        print id, ids[id], pass[id], he[id], ho[id]
}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo in your input, where you put `...98` instead of `...99`. Assuming this is the case, your other information and expected output makes sense.

Using an array to store the ids to preserve the original order of the ids.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';    # to enable say()

my $hdr = <DATA>;  # remove header
my %hash;
my @keys;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($id,$pos,$re,$va,$cn,$sf,$sr,$he,$ho,$nc) = split;
    $id =~ s/^c\K/m/;
    $hash{$id}{he} += $he;
    $hash{$id}{ho} += $ho;
    $hash{$id}{pass}{$sf}++;
    $hash{$id}{count}++;
    push @keys, $id if $hash{$id}{count} == 1;
}
say join "\t", qw(Id CountId Countpass CountHe CountHO);
for my $id (@keys) {
    say join "\t", $id,
        $hash{$id}{count},             # occurences of id
        scalar keys $hash{$id}{pass},  # the number of unique passes
        @{$hash{$id}}{qw(he ho)};
}


__DATA__
Id           Pos Re   Va  Cn   SF:R1   SR  He  Ho NC       
c|371443199  22  G     A    R   Pass:8   0   1  0  0       
c|371443199  25  C     A    M   Pass:13  0   0  1  0
c|371443199  22  G     A    R   Pass:8   0   1  0  0        
c|367079424  17  C     G    S   Pass:19  0   0  1  0      
c|371443198  17  G     A    R   Pass:18  0   1  0  0       
c|367079424  17  G     A    R   Pass:18  0   0  1  0
```

**Output:**

```
Id      CountId Countpass       CountHe CountHO
cm|371443199    3       2       2       1
cm|367079424    2       2       0       2
cm|371443198    1       1       1       0
```

Note: I made the output tab-delimited for easier post-processing. If you want it pretty instead, use `printf` to get some fixed width fields.

Comment: `use v5.10` implies the code requires a special feature of Perl v5.10. You should either `use feature 'say'` or change your comment.

Comment: @Borodin Actually my comment is correct, because I use v5.10 to enable `say` in this specific case. But you are correct in that someone else might incorrectly assume that is all it does.

Comment: then it is worth noting that it also enables `strict`

Comment: `perl -e 'use v5.10; $x=0'` gives no strict errors. You must be thinking of `v5.12`

Comment: I don't think it's a typo. I think that 98 line just isn't represented in the output since the other counts are consistent. But there is a typo in the IDs: "c" vs. "cm". It's interesting that you use `\K` instead of `$&`, but it must be one of those Perl's "dozens of ways".

Comment: @DennisWilliamson `$&` would be the least efficient way. Capturing and using `$1` would the "standard" way. I like the `\K` (keep) escape. You can also use look-around assertions.